# Android include layout below element

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, layout, include

I would like to create a layout as in the image. 
It did not include him, so the code is very long. 
I want to create a layout for each BOX and include it in the main layout, one below the other.

[image]

The problem is that the XML file a layout of this type is very long. 
So I would use includes layout and create a new layout which then repeatedly will include, for example:

I have a RelativeLayout, and I have an ImageView for the line1, below I want to design the box in this method to reduce the code:

```
<include layout = "box1"
layoutBelow = "linea1"
/>
```

And the same for the box 2:

```
<include layout = "box2"
layoutBelow = "linea2"
/>
```

But the layout I include not aligned as I would like. 
The layout is     superimposed on the existing one.

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: If you using this then you need to pass `@id` `layoutBelow = "@id/linea1"`. same for `layoutBelow = "@id/linea2"`.

Comment: maybe https://jsfiddle.net/ can help, paste your code into it and post the link here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have solved in this way:

```
<!-- LINE SEPARATOR 1-->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/logo"
    android:id="@+id/linea1"
    android:background="@drawable/linea"
    />

<!-- BOX1 -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/linea1"
    >

    <include
        layout="@layout/box1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- LINE SEPARATOR 2-->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/logo"
    android:id="@+id/linea2"
    android:background="@drawable/linea"
    />

<!-- BOX2 -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/linea2"
    >

    <include
        layout="@layout/box2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the result is this image:

[image]

Thanks you all :)

Comment: It's the only way I made it work, but it's a little weird to depend on a RelativeLayout each time you want to use an include, the way Android builds interfaces is really annoying :S

Answer (score 3):

Android Studio informs me that for these types of includes to work that `layout_width` and `layout_height` must also be specified in the include tag, otherwise `layout_below` is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

All the last answers are some corrected, first of all if you want to use `id` the `linea1` layout must have it. For example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/id_linea1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

and the include it using

```
<include 
         layout="@layout/box1"
         android:layout_below="@id/id_linea1"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

linea2 also must be below box1 and to work well on a RelativeLayout.

And maybe a LinearLayout with vertical orientation would be better for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like any view :

```
    <include
    layout="@layout/content_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/id_linea1" />
```